# php regex replace each character with asterisk

Tags: php, regex, lookbehind

I am trying to something like this.

Hiding users except for first 3 characters.

EX)

- apple -> app**
- google -> goo***
- abc12345 ->abc*****

I am currently using php like this:

```
$string = "abcd1234";
$regex = '/(?<=^(.{3}))(.*)$/';
$replacement = '*';
$changed = preg_replace($regex,$replacement,$string);
echo $changed;
```

and the result be like:

```
abc*
```

But I want to make a replacement to every single character except for first 3 - like:

```
abc*****
```

How should I do?

Comment: Why use a regex for this? You can do this with some simple logic (substring of first three characters concatenated with string of '*' of length (str.length - 3))

Comment: @PeterG develop your suggestion into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex matches all symbols after the first 3, thus, you replace them with a one hard-coded `*`.

You can use

```
'~(^.{3}|(?!^)\G)\K.~'
```

And replace with `*`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX7tA7/2)

This regex matches the first 3 characters (with `^.{3}`) or the end of the previous successful match or start of the string (with `(?!^)\G`), and then omits the characters matched from the match value (with `\K`) and matches any character but a newline with `.`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/NC71cD)

```
$re = '~(^.{3}|(?!^)\G)\K.~'; 
$strs = array("aa","apple", "google", "abc12345", "asdddd"); 
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    $result = preg_replace($re, "*", $s);
    echo $result . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! this is what i really wanted!! and can you tell me what is the '~' characters in the front and back? is the php regex have different special characters?

Comment: The `~` is a [**regex delimiter**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Usually, people use `/`, but I find `~` better since there is no need escaping `/` symbols in the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex, use [substr_replace](http://www.php.net/substr_replace):

```
$var = "abcdef";
$charToKeep = 3;
echo strlen($var) > $charToKeep ?  substr_replace($var, str_repeat ( '*' ,  strlen($var) - $charToKeep), $charToKeep) : $var;
```

---

Keep in mind that regex are good for matching patterns in string, but there is *a lot* of functions already designed for string manipulation.

Will output:

> abc***

Answer (score 2):

Try this function. You can specify how much chars should be visible and which character should be used as mask:

```
$string = "abcd1234";

echo hideCharacters($string, 3, "*");

function hideCharacters($string, $visibleCharactersCount, $mask)
{
    if(strlen($string) < $visibleCharactersCount)
        return $string;

    $part = substr($string, 0, $visibleCharactersCount);
    return str_pad($part, strlen($string), $mask, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}
```

Output:

> abc*****

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to concatenate the first three characters with a string of `*` repeated the correct number of times:

```
$text = substr($string, 0, 3).str_repeat('*', max(0, strlen($string) - 3));
```

The usage of [`max()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) is needed to avoid [`str_repeat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) issue a warning when it receives a negative argument. This situation happens when the length of `$string` is less than 3.